# WIX : Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0)

Tags: wix, wix3.7, windows-installer

I am getting below message in the log file while uninstalling hotfix .

WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\INSTALLDIR\XXX' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).

Is this a error to be avoided. What is the solution?

Please some one throw some light on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Those messages aren't significant unless you're tryiing to defeat the system. X86 installs must go the the x86 ProgramFiles folder, not to the 64-bit one. Without more context about what you're doing there's no proper answer as to whether it's a problem or not. In tour case, it doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW for your response. I am installing setup which is built with x86 setting in 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

No This is not an error.
This may happen if the installed file have a higher file version than in the setup package.

This can be normally seen during upgrade installation.

Scenario can be Coexistance of two softwares where both software used same dependency software but with different versions and the software with lower version of dependency was upgraded after upgrade of software with higher version of dependency software.

So this is expected. If the file needs to be replaced you should update the file version in the latest installer.